# How to use tensorarray to unstack a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

when I want to unstack a tensor into a tensorarray, it do not take the values of that tensor. Instead, it just take into its shape.
I am using tf1.5, Any help? thanks a lots

Here is my code:

```
emb = tf.Variable([[1,2,3,5],[4,5,6,7]],name = 'emb')
ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size= 2)
ta.unstack(emb)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print(sess.run(emb))
    print(sess.run(ta.stack()))
```

this is the output:

```
[[1 2 3 5]
 [4 5 6 7]]
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

From tensorflow's documentation on unstack (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray):

> Returns: A new TensorArray object with flow that ensures the unstack occurs. Use this object all for subsequent operations.

So the line should be `ta = ta.unstack(emb)`